# Can a Python function return None without throwing a type error if I haven't specified None as a return type?

Tags: python, types

This feels like a simple question, and I believe the answer is yes, but here goes:
I have a function that's explicitly typed to return an object type, let's say `Student`. Can the function return `None` without having to change the return type to `Union["None", "Student"]`?

```py
def get_student(id: string) -> Student:
  student = Student.objects.get(id=id)
  return student
```

Comment: it's just a `type hint` and it's not forced to follow that hint.

Comment: @danangjoyoo thank you! I know way more JS/TS than Python and in TS it's forced